# VS SDK Walkthrough. Displaying light bulbs suggestions - Issues at build time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I am trying to follow this walkthrough https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903708.aspx which is not working at all for me.

I am having the following two issues:

First of all I am having missing references for this piece of code:

```
public ImageMoniker IconMoniker
{
   get { return default(ImageMoniker); }
}
```

The errors I get at build time are two:

> Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded interop type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging.Interop.ImageMoniker'. Are you missing
>   an assembly reference?
>
> The type or namespace name 'ImageMoniker' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

However, I was able (I guess) to fix that by adding this reference: **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging.Interop.14.0.DesignTime**

Second of all, now that I am able to build, the light bulb does not appear at all when I execute the code and create a new *.txt file and I enter some text. I tried to add some breakpoints in the source code but they never get hit (they are being loaded though).

Any idea what's going on? Did anybody try the same and worked for him? Maybe and outdated tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Try double clicking you .vsixmanifest, click assets button, click new, click type drop down and select MefComponent, click source dropdown and select "a project in current solution", for project select your project, then click ok and run it.

Dont do this if you already have a mefcomponent asset for your project, I have found that whenever I use MEF, and forget to add that I loose half my hair before I remeber.